# Jquery tr:last giving undefined?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, undefined, addition

I have a table that is added dynamically, and would like to add row the table.

I believe I had previously used `$("#tbl1 tr:last").after()` to add the row. Currently it is returning as **undefined**.

I attempted `$("#tbl1").children("tr:last")` which worked?

I'm not sure if this really is the right way to do it, but it does work.

Why first option return **undefined**?

Comment: Not without seeing your HTML, no. Have you considered posting your code and adding a demo?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem?

Comment: If you just want to append a row, use `$...appendTo("table")` or `$...appendTo("tbody")`.

Comment: `undefined` must be the consequence of something other than the selector. If the selector was wrong, then you get an empty jQuery collection but no error. Post the HTML, the bad and the good jQuery expressions in full, then maybe folk can advise.

Comment: Can say much without seeing actual HTML and JQuery code. But did you tried `$("#tbl1 > tr:last").after()` instead?